# What does Apache Beam mean by "combining functions are not necessarily invoked exactly once"?

Tags: apache-beam, idempotent

In the [*Tour of Beam* documentation on combine functions](https://tour.beam.apache.org/tour/python/core-transforms/combine/simple-function), it says the following:

> When you apply a Combine transform, you must provide the function that contains the logic for combining the elements or values. The combining function should be commutative and associative, **as the function is not necessarily invoked exactly once on all values with a given key**. Because the input data (including the value collection) may be distributed across multiple workers, the combining function might be called multiple times to perform partial combining on subsets of the value collection

For a combine function, the emphasized phrase above seemed like a *huge* limitation that would drastically complicate how to create a function. But then in the [very next section of the tutorial](https://tour.beam.apache.org/tour/python/core-transforms/combine/combine-fn), there is an example which breaks this restriction, *as I understand it*:

Example averager in tutorial:

```py
class AverageFn(beam.CombineFn):
  def create_accumulator(self):
    return (0.0, 0)

  def add_input(self, sum_count, input):
    (sum, count) = sum_count
    return sum + input, count + 1

  def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
    sums, counts = zip(*accumulators)
    return sum(sums), sum(counts)

  def extract_output(self, sum_count):
    (sum, count) = sum_count
    return sum / count if count else float('NaN')
```

and the tutorial says:

> a local accumulator tracks the running sum of values (the numerator value for our final average division) and the number of values summed so far (the denominator value). **It may be called any number of times in a distributed fashion**.

---

To explain my question / confusion, let me create a toy example with the values

```py
[5, 15, 1004, -3, -8, 11]
```

and let's say that `PCollection` is split across two "instances":

```py
[15, 1004, 11]
[5, -3, -8]
```

*As I understand the documentation*, it is saying that an average of the first subset, `[15, 1004, 11]`, might be calculated twice, while the second one only once, for instance.

That would create an average of `228` instead of `171`, if I "double-counted" the representation of `[15, 1004, 11]`.

---

This is obviously not what happens, so what am I missing?

I understand that the class provides functions that are completely commutative and associative, *but not functions that are idempotent, which is what is implied when saying they are 100% correct even when "not necessarily invoked exactly once"*.

This is important to understand -- how many times can a combiner function be called? -- because:

- It is *clear to me* by going through the provided examples that I don't *truly* need to create idempotent methods.
- But if I don't need to make something idempotent, *what do I need to watch out for*?

  - (And why do they mention that the function may be invoked more than once on the same subset of data?)

---

I am a statistician by training, so I first thought that maybe there is some sort of [Law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) phenomenon, where there is no guarantee of exact correctness, but a discrepancy that is vanishingly small when working with the large datasets used with Beam.

But I think this is untrue, and the answers will be completely deterministic, even on large datasets (excluding windowing and watermarking issues, which may inject some randomness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missread the documentation. `Not necessarily invoked exactly once on all values` means that it is either invoked

- once on all the incoming data (in your example `[5, 15, 1004, -3, -8, 11]`)
- in bundles (in your example two bundles `[15, 1004, 11]` and `[5, -3, -8]`)

It does not mean (in this context) that the incoming data is processed twice. Furthermore, `it may be called any number of times in a distributed fashion` means that the bundles can take any form and are defined during runtime by the runner, i.e. it could be any permutation of

- `[5, 15, 1004, -3, -8, 11]`
- `[5]`,  `[15, 1004, -3, -8, 11]`
- `[5, 15]`,  `[1004, -3, -8, 11]`
- ...
- `[5]`, `[15]`,  `[1004]`, `[-3]`, `[-8]` , `[11]`

That's why it states

> [...] Because the input data (including the value collection) may be
> distributed across multiple workers, the combining function might be
> **called multiple times** to perform **partial combining on subsets** of the
> value collection

and why `The combining function should be commutative and associative [...]`

Comment: Awesome, thanks @CaptainNabla !  Yes, as you point out, I knew I was misunderstanding it... I mean, I knew it worked properly.  But the documentation was not nearly as clear as your example, and now knowing what they _really_ meant to say, I can more confidently write `CombineFn`s, `PTransform`s, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would not hurt if they would change the documentation to '[..] called multiple times to perform partial combining on `disjunct` subsets'

Comment: Yes.  But I also think the phrase "as the function is not necessarily invoked exactly once on all values with a given key" is especially poor.  It should instead say something like, "not necessarily invoked on the entire dataset at once, however each element in the iterable is guaranteed to be visited only once".